# Instagram feed on my website based on hash tag from RSS page

Tags: php, jquery, instagram

I am trying to develop an Instagram feed for a friend.
He wants to show a feed of every picture that's hashtagged "Individen".
I found a webpage that shows all pictures that have that tag - EVEN makes a rss for that.

How can I grab the images from the RSS and display them in a plain feed?
For instance, the 5 most recent pictures.

All the pictures displayed
http://web.stagram.com/tag/individen/?vm=grid

The RSS
http://web.stagram.com/rss/tag/individen/

What method would be best to get the feed? php, JQuery or json?

Answer (score 0):

ALL (PHP , JQuery , JSON)

Make ajax call using jquery to php page.
Using feedparser parse the rss feed and get what you want .
return json containing image url and data that you want to display.

Comment: Thanks!
i'll hope ill be able to do it :)